# Unable To Save Or Run Import/Export Dataflow Profiles

Tags: magento-1.7, product, export, importexport, dataflow

I have recently started experiencing issues when saving or running any dataflow profiles in Magento. When trying to do so I get the following error message:

> Please set available and/or protected paths list(s) before validation.

After reviewing the code I came across the following inside the Mage_ImportExport_Helper_Data class on or around line 57:

```
public function getLocalValidPaths()
{
    $paths = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/file/importexport_local_valid_paths');
    return $paths;
}
```

This function is setting the returning a list of paths that are allowed to be inputted. The variable being returned is null everytime even though the following is set in the Mage_ImportExport extensions config.xml file:

```
<default>
    <general>
        <file>
            <importexport_local_valid_paths>
                <available>
                    <export_xml>var/export/*/*.xml</export_xml>
                    <export_csv>var/export/*/*.csv</export_csv>
                    <import_xml>var/import/*/*.xml</import_xml>
                    <import_csv>var/import/*/*.csv</import_csv>
                </available>
            </importexport_local_valid_paths>
            <bunch_size>100</bunch_size>
        </file>
    </general>
</default>
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before and know how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `system.xml` in `Mage_ImportExport`, therefore you can not edit this setting in the backend.

You might still want to check `core_config_data`, just in case some  data or install script did something with this setting. The path should be `general/file/importexport_local_valid_paths` `(/available?)` So just search for `LIKE %general/file/importexport_local_valid_paths%`

And the last idea I have is, that for some reason, you overwrite this setting in some other `config.xml` or `app/etc/local.xml`

Comment: Hi Fabian, Thanks for your reply. What setting should I be looking for in particular inside the core_config_data table?

Comment: edited the answer to add this info :)

Comment: Thanks Fabian. The row was missing from the table so must have been removed in the past some how. Thanks again for your help.